# Autocomplete in opensearch

Tags: c#, web-services, autocomplete, opensearch

I have done autocomplete functionality for opensearch using WCF. But we are using 3.5, so I now need to achieve the same without using WCF.

Any idea or please send me any useful link.

My scenario is when I type name, it should fetch related name from db and display. I have a webmethod to fetch data from db. All I need is how to mention the template in opensearch.xml. I was mentioning wcfservice.

please help me

Comment: WCF was already present in .NET 3.5.x

Comment: WCF was released with .NET Framework 3.0

Answer (score 2):

You need the following syntax in your search.xml file:

```
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="http://www.example.com/searchcontroller/{searchTerms}"/>
```

If someone starts typing in *fre* the method on the search controller that looks for suggestions should then return a JSON array of suggestions in this format:

```
["fre", ["frequent", "freeze", "freak"]]
```

Have a look at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Supporting_search_suggestions_in_search_plugins)